# Box Scroldown with page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'want that my box scroll down with my page but this script seem dosn't work her's my code:

CSS

```
/* Print and Download Buttons */
#box {top: 271px;}
a.print{ background:#ffffff url(images/bg-print.jpg) no-repeat top center; border:1px solid #ccc; display:block; height:24px; padding:2px; 
         position:absolute; right:765px; text-indent:-9999px; top:271px; width:24px; z-index:110; }

a.download{ background:#ffffff url(images/bg-download.jpg) no-repeat top center; border:1px solid #ccc; display:block; height:24px; padding:2px;
            position:absolute; right:765px; text-indent:-9999px; top:300px; width:24px; z-index:111; }

    a.print:hover, a.download:hover{ padding-right:12px; }
```

HTML Code :

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_layout/js/costum.js"></script> <!--The Js file call !-->
<!-- My div Box that's i want to scroll down !-->
        <div id="box"> 
            <a href="javascript:window.print()" id="print" title="Print CV" class="tip print">Print CV</a>
            <a href="#" id="download" title="Download CV" class="tip download">Download CV</a>
            </div>
```

And this is my costum.js

```
    window.onload = function() {

  function getScrollTop() {
    if (typeof window.pageYOffset !== 'undefined' ) {
      // Most browsers
      return window.pageYOffset;
    }

    var d = document.documentElement;
    if (d.clientHeight) {
      // IE in standards mode
      return d.scrollTop;
    }

    // IE in quirks mode
    return document.body.scrollTop;
  }

  window.onscroll = function() {
    var box = document.getElementById('box'),
        scroll = getScrollTop();

    if (scroll <= 300) {
      box.style.top = "300px";
    }
    else {
      box.style.top = (scroll + 2) + "px";
    }
  };

};
```

Comment: You could try using fixed positioning in CSS.

Comment: @William `position:fixed` would be a good solution but at the top of the page it must not be at the top of the screen. think you would still need javascript to handle that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `position:absolute` on the `a` tags not `box` so setting `top` will not affect its position. Move `position` to the div and it should work fine:

```
/* Print and Download Buttons */
#box {
    position:absolute;
    right:765px;
    top:271px;
}

a.print {
    background:#f00;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    display:block;
    height:24px;
    padding:2px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    width:24px;
    z-index:110;
}

a.download {
    background:#c00;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    display:block;
    height:24px;
    padding:2px;
    position:absolute;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    width:24px;
    z-index:111;
}

a.print:hover, a.download:hover {
    padding-right:12px;
}
```